# How to disable Apple Push Notification Service (apsd) which is trying to bypass firewalls

Tags: macos, notifications, firewall, services, apns

I am using an iMac at work, and the IT security guys are raising issue with the Apple Push Notification Service (apsd) trying to bypass the proxy continually.

I would like to know how I can disable apsd from running.

Comment: I know that apsd uses port 5223, so I was thinking I could just close that port, but not sure if this would work or if it would just assign another port to the service...

Comment: For info.: the repetitive access attempt through a proxy are blocked and produce the typical logging `1564623170.835      0 10.0.2.22 TCP_DENIED/403 3980 CONNECT 17.242.89.246:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html`. They are using 443 (i.e. https) toward 17.0.0.0/8 without DNS name (which is the reason my proxy is blocking it: don't connect with anonymous servers).

Comment: Same kind of problem on MacOS 10.9, 10.10, 10.11, 10.12, 10.13.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I figured out that I needed to enter the following in the terminal:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.apsd.plist
```

I did this already, and it seemed to fix the issue, but would love to know if this is the advisable way to solve the problem.

========================================================

Also, in case you want to enable the process afterwards, you can use this:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.apsd.plist
```

sources:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/disabling-unnecessary-mac-osx-services/

Comment: with latest macOS I receive this error `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.apsd.plist: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged`. Any idea howto disable this spyware service? I don't wish to reduce security with `csrutil disable`. Thanks

Comment: @Ivanov are you still seeing the same error on Mojave?

Comment: `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.apsd.plist: Could not find specified service` on 10.13.6

Comment: This answer [may not be correct for newer OS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/413994/5472) but it certainly worked easily in 2013.

Answer (score 5):

`Little Snitch` is a means to solve this problem.  It doesn't answer the original question (which is how to disable `apsd` from running), but it can solve this sort of problem, albeit in a bandaid way, that the author of the question has.

With `Little Snitch` in place it's one button click solution to never hear from `apsd` again...

Comment: It was Little Snitch that made me aware this service was sending data to the Indonesian ISP/government. The program also allowed me to disable it with a single toggle.

Comment: You are right: this is a "bandaid approach". The communication between `apsd`, `MacOS` and `Little Snitch` continues forever to block it from reaching the outside: a swarm of bees locked in a bottle.

Answer (score 2):

Little snitch will only work for a little while.  APSD will continue to try to connect to multiple ip addresses once you "deny" connection.  I had to do it like 40 times, then when I thought everything was blocked it started doing it again a couple months later relentlessly.  Turn the stupid process off.

Comment: It would be helpful to edit your answer and let let people know how to do that.  Also is your answer based on (the rather dated question OS X version) 10.8?  As an aside, LS might have been prompting you per-port, and maybe the daemon was randomizing the port since you kept blocking it.

Comment: LittleSnitch is a mess as for some reason ObjectiveDevelopment have been co-opted and do not have easy ways to help us stop Apple phoning home. Been that way since about 10.8.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.apsd.plist
```

this will completely stop apsd as your background service.  Similar in linux, for those process that are running in `/etc/inittab`

Answer (score 0):

sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.applepushserviced.plist

For 10.7.5 FYI. The service name is expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it will be a safer alternative to use Little Snitch and a customized Hosts File to Block Apple stuff you don't want (If you are not planning to use Apple related services such as FaceTime, Messages, App Store and so on) You could also block, at the DNS level, Apple related domains that such process use.

### Per Example:

Hostnames:  a1441.g4.akamai.net
        init-p01st.push.apple.com.edgesuite.net
        init-p01st.push.apple.com
    IP Addresses:   184.28.188.170
        184.28.188.163
    ---
Hostnames:  35.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        24-courier.push.apple.com
        21-courier.push.apple.com
        13.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        9-courier.push.apple.com
        6-courier.push.apple.com
        32.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        13-courier.push.apple.com
        34-courier.push.apple.com
        17.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        34.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        47.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        46-courier.push.apple.com
        39-courier.push.apple.com
        9.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        47-courier.push.apple.com
        11-courier.push.apple.com
        43-courier.push.apple.com
        14-courier.push.apple.com
        19-courier.push.apple.com
        41-courier.push.apple.com
        8.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        1-courier.push.apple.com
        24.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        17-courier.push.apple.com
        21.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        10-courier.push.apple.com
        38.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        38-courier.push.apple.com
        6.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        32-courier.push.apple.com
        8-courier.push.apple.com
        35-courier.push.apple.com
        18-courier.push.apple.com
        1.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        43.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        11.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        10.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        sjc-courier.push-apple.com.akadns.net
        19.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        18.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        14.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        46.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        41.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
        39.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net
    IP Addresses:   17.249.28.28
        17.249.28.27
        17.249.28.30
        17.249.28.19
        17.249.28.36
        17.249.28.22
        17.249.28.31
        17.249.28.12
        17.249.28.21
        17.249.28.25
        17.249.28.32
        17.249.28.8
        17.249.28.24
        17.249.28.10
        17.249.28.18
        17.249.28.11
        17.249.28.33
        17.249.28.34
        17.249.28.13
        17.249.28.23
        17.249.28.26
        17.249.28.35
        17.249.28.20
        17.249.28.15
        17.249.28.17
    ----

The above, is just a small example of all Apple's process / services phoning home. The full list is Extensive. I block them at both; At the App level (Using Little Snitch) and at the DNS level (Hosts File) because they Tend to bypass or go around the back of VPN connections. So, I consider them a Privacy and Security Breach. I Love my Mac, but I don't use any apple related apps and services.

AS per Little Snitch, you have to Uncheck some predefined settings. So, next time an Apple process kicks in, such as the apsd process, you can then choose to block all outgoing connections.

To Edit the Hosts File on your Mac, Open Finder, Go to Folder, write: /etc/hosts and the open using TextWrangler. Don't forget to use  0.0.0.0  as a Prefix on all your entries, you can use other commands on TextWrangler such as Sort, Add Line Breaks, and so on. Then, just save and reboot.

If you try to Disable some Apple process via Terminal, you may be required to disable first SIP, which I personally preferred to live it alone. (Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged)

Answer (score 0):

It may also help if you turn off the "Find My Mac" feature, found in the iCloud settings.

At least in my case, where I got the message `sleep prevented by apsd` for the command `pmset -g`, this made the message go away.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution would be to use Little Snitch and to block apsd from there.