# I disabled Apple Push Notification Service but it's still attempting to connect to Apple servers

Tags: macos, mojave, notifications, apns

I disabled the service as per the instructions on this page: 
[How to disable Apple Push Notification Service (apsd) on OS X 10.8?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92214/how-to-disable-apple-push-notification-service-apsd-on-os-x-10-8)

Yet this service is still running at startup!

How do I disable it once and for all?

Edit: I'm using Mojave

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question.

Comment: Case39, are you saying that the correct answer on the page you linked doesn’t work?

Comment: Like I said, it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Found this googling around:

> If you don't use FaceTime, put this in a Terminal window to get rid of apsd permanently: "sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.apsd.plist"

This will unload apsd from launchctl (the process that launches it at startup), but you'll still need to kill now.

Comment: This is what I did after disabling System Integrity Protection, but apsd is still trying to connect to Apple servers about every 4 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I finally just changed the permission of /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/apsd after disabling System Integrity Protection and reenabling it when done.

I'm still wondering why I couldn't disable apsd the normal way though.

Comment: Update: Strangely, the Apple Push Service Daemon has resumed trying to connect to Appler servers. I don't know if it's the Catalina upgrade that messed with the file's permission.